# show/hide columns in SSRS report 2012 based on Multiselect parameter

Tags: reporting-services

i have been trying to hide/show columns within my tablix based on multi value parameter , but whenever i am plugging in the expression in the column visibility properties it is not showing what i select from the parameter and hide what is not select. 
Here is the expression: 
`=IIF(InStr(JOIN(Parameters!parameter.Value,", "),"value"),false,true)`

any help???

Comment: So basically you or getting the oposite of what you expecting right then just change your expression to `=IIF(InStr(JOIN(Parameters!parameter.Value,", "),"value"),true,false)`

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you want to show the column if you select a value which contains "value". Right?

So the expression should be like below:

=IIF(InStr(JOIN(Parameters!parameter.Value,","),"value")>0,false,true)

Answer (score 1):

I always get this wrong too. I think backwards. It is actually asking for the expression that will hide the column. SO Black_T is correct with his answer.

=IIF(InStr(JOIN(Parameters!Parameter.Value,","),"value")>0,false, true)

so whenever the expression picks up that value in the statement, it will return false, meaning that it should not hide it, and whenever it doesn't find it, well the returned product will also hide it! pretty ingenious!

Thanks and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

```
=IIF(InStr(JOIN(Parameters!parameter.Value,","),"value")>0,true,false)
```