# ssrs hide column group based on input parameter SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2, rdl

I am building a report in SQL Server 2008 R2 using Report builder 3.0. I have a column group Called committee which has values Committee1, Committee2, Committee3. Column Group committee expands into three columns Person, Contact, Company.

Input to report is based on multiselect parameter.

Reference:
[show/hide columns in SSRS report 2012 based on Multiselect parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244115/show-hide-columns-in-ssrs-report-2012-based-on-multiselect-parameter)

My requirement is if Committee 1 is selected from input, the report should show the column group committee not Committee2 and Committee3. 
I know how to show or hide columns based on input parameter but not for column group.

Please help.

Comment: Check the "Advanced" box to view Column Groups, select one, and modify the "Hidden" property same as for a column.

Comment: Can anyone share the expression not the procedure..?

Comment: But you say " I know how to show or hide columns based on input parameter".   The expression is exactly the same, you just do it on the column group instead of the column.

Comment: ok.. thank you.. I was under impression that there is a separate expression for column group.. it is working..

Answer (score 0):

Right click column->colmun visibility->**Show or hide based on and expression**
Then write your show hide statement.

Comment: I dont know how to write the statement.

Comment: have a look this link or search in google as "ssrs column visibility" http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/conditionally-setting-column-visibility-in-ssrs/